# Javamelody Counter instance taking up a lot of space

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, heap-memory, java-melody

We have a module deployed on `tomcat 7` in production and using `javamelody 1.49.0` to analyze performance.

Our infrastructure team reported an issue in production where `Javamelody's` Counter seemed to take around `900 MB` potentially due to a memory leak. is this a known issue. It happens after few days of usage like every other week and we do NOT know what is causing this.

Does anyone have an idea on this ?

[image: Error message from heapdump production]

Comment: Do you have Javamelody configured to keep track of some huge number of data points? Perhaps it's doing exactly what you asked it to do...

Comment: what do you mean huge number of data points ?

Comment: different http requests perhaps, you should use a transform-filter to narrow down the url javamelody monitors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently had this exact same issue because we had mis-configured the `javamelody.storage-directory`.

JavaMelody logs someting like: `exception while collecting data: java.io.IOException: JavaMelody directory can't be created: /path/to/storage/dir/_4814f02a7626` in the logs section of the web-interface.

It appears that Java Melody keeps all request data in memory when it is unable to write its data to the storage location causing this massive memory leak. This memory leak turns up in the heap dump as an huge instance of class `net.bull.javamelody.internal.model.Counter`.